# How to cache data on server in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am working on mvc4 web application. I want to cache some database queries results and views on server side. I used-

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert()
```

but it caches the data on client side. Please help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm using MemoryCache to store query results, and it's working fine so far.
Here are a few links that I've used to implement it.
- [Using MemoryCache in .NET 4.0 (codeproject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net-4-0)
- [Using MemoryCache in .NET 4.0 (blog entry)](http://dineshmandal.wordpress.com/2011/11/27/using-memorycache-in-net-4-0/)

As I read them now, I find them not that clear, so maybe there is a better link that I've lost somewhere.
Here is a sample of my code which I hope is clear enough so that you see how it works

```
public static class AgencyCacheManager
{
    private static MemoryCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

    public static List<RefAgency> ListAgency
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_cache.Contains("ListAgency"))
                RefreshListAgency();
            return _cache.Get("ListAgency") as List<Agency>;
        }
    }

    public static void RefreshListAgency()
    {
        var listAgency = GetAllComplete();

        CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        _cache.Add("ListAgency", listAgency, cacheItemPolicy);
    }
}
```

And to retrieve the list from cache

```
public Agency FindBy(string agencyId)
{
    return AgencyCacheManager.ListAgency.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AgencyPartnerCode == agencyId);
}
```

Comment: Great, SIMPLE, explanation.  Thanks!